# Minimalizing namespaces for custom functions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a StringUtilities.cs file in the CommonFunctions Project that holds a UppercaseFirst function that Uppercases the first word in a string.  Currently in the .aspx.cs in a separate Project (in the same Solution) that is utilizing this function is called using **MyProject.CommonFunctions.StringUtilities.UppercaseFirst("hello world");**

Is it possible to shorten it to just **UppercaseFirst("hello world");**  ?  Readability will be so much better.

StringUtilities.cs in the CommonFunctions Project:

```
namespace MyProject.CommonFunctions
{
    public class StringUtilities
    {
        public static string UppercaseFirst(string s)
        {//blah code}
    }
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
using MyProject.CommonFunctions;
...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyProject.CommonFunctions.StringUtilities.UppercaseFirst("hello world");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't cut it all the way down to just the method name, but given that you've already got the `using MyProject.CommonFunction;` line in place, you could shorten it to:

```
StringUtilities.UppercaseFirst("hello world");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using c# 3.0 (.NET 3.5) you can use extension methods:

```
namespace MyProject.CommonFunctions
{
    public static class StringUtilities
    {
        public static string UppercaseFirst(this string s)
        {//blah code}
    }
}
```

Once you set your usings in appropriate file you can then go:

```
using MyProject.CommonFunctions;
...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     "hello world".UppercaseFirst();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not in C#; VB.NET (and C++/CLI) have different lookup rules.

In C#, you can use a `using` alias as follows:

```
using StrUtil = MyProject.CommonFunctions.StringUtilities;
```

which would allow you to then write

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     StrUtil.UppercaseFirst("hello world");
}
```

regardless of the enclosing namespace.